# Check if the selection contains graphics

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm trying to write a script where part of it is to find out if there is an image in the objects selected, or the objects are empty shapes.

I need to check if the files of the selection are all images, all shapes or are mixed.

I've put together this code with alerts (the final code will not be with alerts, it's for understanding purposes):

```
    if (app.selection.length == 0) {
        alert ("Nothing selected");
        }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < app.selection.length; i++) {
            if ((app.selection[i].graphics.length == 0) && (app.selection[i].graphics.length == 1)) {
                alert ("The files are mixed");
                }
            else if (app.selection[i].graphics.length == 1) {
                alert ("The files are images");
                }
            else if (app.selection[i].graphics.length == 0) {
                alert ("The files are shapes");
                }
            }
        }
```

Obviously the code is not working as intended (it works for the images and the shapes, while I already know the mixed part it's not written correctly), since my searches have been inconclusive.

What I'm looking for is: if nothing is selected (do something), else if the files are shapes and images (do something only to the shapes), else if there are only images (do something), else if there are only shapes (do something).

Can someone give me an idea on how to do it?

Comment: How it's supposed to handle groups?

Comment: It shouldn't, only images and shapes.

Comment: There are shapes with images inside. And there are shapes without images inside. What do you mean by a 'mixed' objects?

Comment: By images I mean a selection of frames with a graphic image inside (like when you import an image), by shapes I mean a selection of frames without graphic inside (they could be the shape tool's rectangle, oval or polygon, or the frames tool's ones). By mixed I mean a selection of both.

Comment: The final script will be: if nothing selected > create a white rectangle, if only images selected > create a white rectangle, if only shapes selected > color the shapes white, if the selection is mixed > color only the shapes white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the algo can be something like this:

```
var sel = app.selection;

if (sel.length == 0) alert('Nothing selected');

else {

    var images = sel.pop().graphics.length > 0;
    var mixed = false;

    while (sel.length) {
        if ((sel.pop().graphics.length > 0) != images) {
            mixed = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (mixed) alert('Mixed');
    else {
        if (images) alert('Images');
        else alert('Shapes');
    }
}
```

But it doesn't handle groups.

**Update**

If you just want to get shapes (and omit images) from the selection it can be done this way:

```
var sel = app.selection;
if (sel.length == 0) { alert('Nothing selected'); exit() }

var shapes = [];
for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++)
    if (sel[i].graphics.length == 0) shapes.push(sel[i]);

if (shapes.length > 0) do_something(shapes);

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
function do_something(shapes) {
    alert('Here we go...');
    app.selection = shapes;

    // do stuff...
}
```

Or a short variant (just to deselect images):

```
var sel = app.selection;
for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++)
    if (sel[i].graphics.length > 0) sel[i].select(SelectionOptions.REMOVE_FROM);
```

**Update 2**

Here is the code that does as follows:

- if nothing selected > creates a white rectangle,
- if only images selected > creates a white rectangle,
- if only shapes selected > colors the shapes white,
- if the selection is mixed > selects only the shapes and colors white.

```
var sel = app.selection;

if (sel.length == 0) fn_nothing();
else {
    var images = sel.pop().graphics.length > 0;
    var mixed = false;
    while (sel.length) {
        if ((sel.pop().graphics.length > 0) != images) {
            mixed = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (mixed) fn_mixed();
    else {
        if (images) fn_images();
        else fn_shapes();
    }
}

function fn_nothing() {
    alert('Nothing');
    create_white_rectangle();
}

function fn_images() {
    alert('Images');
    create_white_rectangle();
}

function fn_shapes() {
    alert('Shapes');
    color_shapes_white();
}

function fn_mixed() {
    alert('Mixed');
    select_shapes();
    color_shapes_white();
}

function select_shapes() {
    var sel = app.selection;
    while (sel.length) {
        var item = sel.pop();
        if (item.graphics.length > 0)
        item.select(SelectionOptions.REMOVE_FROM)
    }
    alert('Select shapes');
}

function color_shapes_white() {
    alert('Color shapes white')
}

function create_white_rectangle() {
    alert('Create a white rectangle');
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use your code and replace the seventeenth line with


        if mixed{
            while (sel.length) {
                if (sel.shift().graphics.length > 0) {
                    sel.shift().select (SelectionOptions.REMOVE_FROM);
                    }
                }


or with



        if mixed{
            for (var a = 0; a < sel.length; a++) {
                if (sel[a].graphics.length > 0) {
                sel[a].select (SelectionOptions.REMOVE_FROM);
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: but it deselect only some images, leaving some selected. Since the alerts are correct, I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: It looks like you have a another (or next?) task. Not the one you describe in your question. So what exactly you're trying to achieve? Can you describe the task step by step?

Comment: In the last part of my question I wrote :

"What I'm looking for is:

if nothing is selected (do something),

else if the files are shapes and images (do something only to the shapes),

else if there are only images (do something),

else if there are only shapes (do something)."

What I'm trying to do is basically deselect the images to "do something only to the shapes"

Comment: There still remain uncertainties what exactly you will do with the shapes. It can be a problem. But anyway, I just added the updated code to my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you, I finally have been able to make it work. Apparently I needed to add "var sel = app.selection;" inside every function that edit the selection, even if it was already present at the beginning of the code.